# Convert jQuery to String in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string

I am trying to convert the object `time` to a String. My current javascript is as follows:

```
var time =
    {
        "time": $("#weeks").val()

    };
```

How would I then convert that time object into a String?

Comment: `JSON.stringify(time)`

Comment: What are you trying to do with your String?

Comment: `time.toString()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`JSON.stringify(time)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Use `JSON.stringify(time)`

To change the string back to a JavaScript object you would use `JSON.parse()`

Answer (score -1):

You seemt to be looking for: JSON.stringify()

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Answer (score -1):

You could try: 
`JSON.stringify(time)`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21032504)

Comment: Why do you consider it not an answer? The question asked, was how to convert an object to a string, I proposed (same as others) solution that clearly does that, I don't understand why you down-voted this and posted this comment. Indeed, OP may want to do something else, but the question remains 'how to convert an object to a string'.

Comment: @TheDude It's the same answer everyone else is giving.